# Source Code References / Debug Symbols in Visual Studio Profiler not working correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling

I seem to have somehow broken my Visual Studio Profiler. When running my app (in Debug mode, with the default CPU Profiling enabled), the "CPU Usage" tab is only partly able to resolve the respective symbols.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, some symbols (like get_Lower()) are correctly resolved to be in module "v4pcore". Other symbols like "IsEmpty()" are part of some mystical "ManagedModule" module. Notice that those two symbols are part of the same class, and also of the same file. Clicking the former shows the corresponding source-code, clicking the latter doesn't work ("unable to find symbol file").

I don't think that the .pdb file is not found, because
(a) I see the respective message in the output-window ("v4pcore.dll. Symbols loaded.") and
(b) the profiling seems to work fine. It does know which functions are hit etc.

Somewhere in the process there seems to be a missing link, and I cannot figure out where.

Maybe somebody has experienced a similar issue and knows what is going on here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your C# project is based on .NET, in Solution Explorer, select the C# project node and select the Properties icon, or right-click the project node and select Properties. Select Debug in the left pane, select Open debug launch profile UI, then uncheck the Enable native code debugging check box, and close the property page to save changes. This turns off mixed-mode debugging. If you test again at this time, will this issue still occur?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT: Native code debugging is already disabled for all projects in the solution